# Object's instance lost when I add an item to the object's List c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an object which I initialize on a page's code behind

Here's an example of this object's class

```
public Class Thing
{
    List<OtherThing> _thisList;
    public List<OtherThing> ThisList
    {
        get { return _thisList; }
        set { _thisList= value; }
    }
    public Thing()
    {
        this._thisList=new List<OtherThing>();
    }
}
```

and here's my page's code behind

```
public partial class form : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Thing theThing = new Thing();

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OtherThing OT = new OtherThing(txtName.Text, Convert.toInt32(txtId.Text);
        TheThing.ThisList.Add(OT);
        this.gridview.DataSource=null;
        this.gridview.DataSource=TheThing.ThisList();
        this.gridview.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Yet each time I add an element, the gridview displays only the latest one added, I tried debugging and found that when I press the button a second time "TheThing"'s list's count displays 0

Comment: You have also a problem to this.. from `private Thing theThing = new Thing()` to `TheThing.ThisList`.. this is wrong. Small Caps `theThing` to `TheThing`.

Comment: I thank your insight, yet this is because I code in spanish and I'm translating my examples, in my real scenario visual studio would point out that it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every time you click the button, it will execute this line

```
private Thing theThing = new Thing();
```

Which is initializing a new object of `Thing`, and in the constructor of that, you are initializing the `ThisList` property to an empty list.

*Put a breakpoint in that line and you can see it*

If you want to persist data between multiple calls, you should persist it somewhere and read from there. You can store it in session state,application state, memory cache, a file in disk or a database.

Remember, **Http is (and should be) stateless**. Ideally every call to your page has no idea what the previous call did. Interestingly, Contradicting to this principle, Webforms uses something  called [ViewState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) to persist data of ui controls (dropdown control etc) between calls (post back on a button click). This is more like a hack to bring the stateful nature (like a windows forms application) to web forms!

BTW, your class can simply use Auto properties, as it is not doing anything fancy with the `set` and `get` operations

```
public class Thing
{
    public List<OtherThing> ThisList { get; set; }
    public Thing()
    {
        this.ThisList = new List<OtherThing>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew it was starting a new one everytime, but I didn't know why, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is Because:

you Declared `this.gridview.DataSource=null;` Everytime when button add was `clicked`.

try to put this in your `Form load` event:

```
this.gridview.DataSource=null;
```

and in your `button Click` Event:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OtherThing OT = new OtherThing(txtName.Text, Convert.toInt32(txtId.Text);
        TheThing.ThisList.Add(OT);
        this.gridview.DataSource=TheThing.ThisList();
        this.gridview.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: How does setting it to `null` affect the assignment to `TheThing.ThisList()`? Sure, it's unnecessary, but in the end the final assignment is the same, isn't it?

Comment: It's is different when button was click than form load event.. Form load event is just a one time execution. than button when everytime user was click. the Op Claimed that the data was lost.. How can you say `final assignment is the same`?

Comment: I mean the final assignment is the same because when you do `this.gridview.DataSource = TheThing.ThisList();`, it doesn't matter what `this.gridview.DataSource` was previously (null, or the "old" list). It's now assigned to `TheThing.ThisList()`, which both your code and his code do.

Comment: The only problem here is this `TheThing.ThisList`.